# Writing a file with vim doesn't fire a file change event on OS X

Tags: python, macos, watchdog, fsevents, kqueue

I am using [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) to monitor .less file change events on OS X. If I change the contents of a .less file with TextMate or Sublime Text the modification event is captured. However, if I edit the content with vim no file modification event is fired (but file creation events for files created with vim are captured). I have seen the same behaviour with FSEvents and kqueue (both of which I have practically zero knowledge of).

I wonder can anybody explain this behaviour?

Comment: Does vim write to a temp file, then rename the temp file to the name of the file you're working on?

Comment: That may be something to do with it. The only spanner in the works is that when I `mv` a file it triggers a move/rename event. I wonder why vim's save doesn't do that? Nothing events are fired when I write from vim. I can see .swp files beings created when I begin editing though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim normally does *not* create a temporary file and then rename it. This is so that filesystem aspects such as links (both soft and hard) are preserved when writing files. This is discussed briefly in the [Writing](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#writing) section of the Vim documentation, with further information in the [`'backupcopy'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27backupcopy%27) option documentation.

Your file change events might be limited to changing directory *entries*.

Comment: Thanks for the information Greg. As I mention above though, I can see the file events when I edit with TextMate or Sublime Text.

Comment: It sounds like those editors write files in a different way than Vim does (perhaps similar to setting the `backupcopy` option to `no` in Vim).

Comment: I set the following: set nobackup, set noswapfile, set nowritebackup; and the modified events were fired.

Comment: FYI, this is documented in the README on github that you linked to.

Comment: For posterity finding this, I believe `set backupcopy=yes` is the key piece: force Vim to write to the original file, not copying it as the backup and writing to a new file. This allows you to keep `set backup` and `set writebackup` if you prefer. `swapfile` is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 4):

On [Watchdog's readme](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) there is a section specifically targeting the problem you describe: About using watchdog with editors like Vim. It is suggested to use `set noswapfile` in your `~/.vimrc`.